# NodeJS: listen on TCP/UDP for IPv6 only

Tags: node.js, tcp, udp, ipv6

How can I bind/listen on a certain port, only for IPv6 (if it's even possible)?

If I bind to `::` it listens on both ipv4/6.
If I bind to `0.0.0.0` it listens only on ipv4.
If I bind to `::1` it listens only on IPv6, but for local only
Is there a way to listen only on TCP/UDP IPv6 with something like `::`?

### UDP Example

The following code:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const s = dgram.createSocket('udp6');
s.bind(23513, "::");
```

Results in both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
netstat -ano | find "23513"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:23513          *:*                                    
  UDP    [::]:23513             *:*
```

And the following:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.bind(23513, "0.0.0.0");
```

Results in only IPv4:

```
netstat -ano | find "23513"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:23513          *:*
```

And `s.bind(23513, "::1");` Results in:

```
netstat -ano | find "23513"
  UDP    [::1]:23513            *:*
```

### TCP Example

```js
const net = require('net');
const s = net.createServer((socket) => {})
s.listen(23513, '::');
```

Results in both:

```
netstat -ano | FIND "23513"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:23513          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:23513             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Related:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9390
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17664
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/23798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with "ipv6Only" flag?

```
const s = dgram.createSocket({ type: 'udp6', ipv6Only: true });
s.bind(23513, '::');
```

For TCP add the flag like below (from comments):

```
s.listen({ipv6Only:true, port: 23513, host: '::'});
```

Comment: What's the equivalent for TCP?
the above works for UDP6 with `::`.

Comment: Found it. for TCP, it's `s.listen({ipv6Only:true, port: 23513, host: '::'});` you should add it to your answer for future reference.